# How to remove git repository created on desktop

Tags: git, windows-7, desktop

I accidentally made my Desktop a git repository. How to remove the git-related files from Desktop?

- I have tried to go to C:/User/my_user/Desktop and un-hide hidden git files but couldn't un-hide them.
- Then I tried to delete the files using Windows Powershell but it isn't listing these files either.
- I have also tried finding options in GitExtensions for some option to delete the git files but couldn't find any such option.
- Couldn't find option in Git GUI

There is a git repository for sure because I can use `GitEx Browse` option in the right click menu.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

remove the hidden folder named .git from your Desktop

Answer (score 22):

If you are a **Comamnd Line Freak!** You can also do it from your command prompt

- Start --> Run
- Type: **cmd**
- Navigate to the folder of your project (ex: **cd c:\myProject** )
- From the folder of your project you can type the following to be able to see the .git folder:
  **attrib -s -h -r *.* /s /d**
- then you can just Delete the .git folder from the command line: **del /F /S /Q /A .git**
- and **rmdir .git**

Comment: use "rmdir -Force -Recurse .git" if its not empty

Comment: 10 years later, still deserves an upvote. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 17):

Go to your project directory and execute the following command on windows
**rmdir /s /q .git** that will remove all of the git references.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:
- Make sure you are logged in with an admin account.
- Navigate, in Explorer, to "C:/User/my_user/".
- Right-click on 'Desktop' and select the 'Security' tab.
- Make sure 'my_user' has full control over the Desktop folder.
- Windows key->"Folder Options"->View: "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
Now try to delete the .git dir and related files from Desktop (via command line or Explorer).

(Apologies if you have tried all these things, just trying to be thorough...)

Answer (score 2):

```
^C[~ (master #)]$ ls -al | grep .git
```

You should see the following files:
.git
.gitconfig

```
qc^C[~ (master #)]$ rm -rf .git
```

(recursively remove the `.git` file)

Answer (score 2):

Display the hidden folders:
`$ ls -alh` .
Remove the .git folder:
`$ rm -R .git`

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the directory where you want to delete your .git folder then type in cmd
   `rmdir /S .git`
2. Or Click on windows option and Go to file explorer option and check "Show hidden files" and remove .git folder
3. If you have github repo and some folder in it has greyed out because of this you can use `git rm --cached submodule-name` and then commit again

Answer (score 0):

Download and install gitbash on your system if its windows or make use of your terminal if you have git install on your system and type the command
rm -fr .git (this will remove the git repo on your system locally)