# Atom editor running slowly in all new projects

Tags: atom-editor

Has anyone had issues recently with Atom slowing down? Mine has become unusably slow, but only for projects that I've created in the last few days. I can edit older projects with no issue, however there's a 5 - 10 second lag when typing and navigating between files in all new projects. The Activity Monitor shows that Atom Helper is often using 100% CPU.

Steps so far:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Atom
- Testing whether opening projects using different languages (Ruby vs Javascript) makes any difference (it doesn't)

Other notes:

- I have the most recent version of Atom installed (1.18.0)
  I've been using Atom for a month without issues
- I haven't changed any of the settings or packages or plugins
- The first project affected was one using Javascript and Jasmine for testing (all previous projects were in Ruby using Rspec)

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Safe Mode via `atom --safe`?

Comment: Hi Pradana - I have and the same issues apply

Comment: Try clearing window state: `atom --clear-window-state`.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't seem to have changed the situation. Another strange behaviour is that sometimes after I've typed a few letters in a file Atom will start repeating these over and over again until I quit the file or type ctrl+C

Comment: I have the same problem, its frustrating. "safe mode" did not work, and I am not sure this is solution even if it had. Moving away from this IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably related to a certain package/s that is taking up a lot of your processing. I recently had a problem where atom would freeze/lag every 20-30s. I would be typing, and it would just freeze, and then about 5-10s later every letter I had pressed would appear. I ended up basically trying a few different things, and eventually ruled out my problem.

I started off by trying to run:

```
atom --safe
```

This command runs atom without the community packages. It is used to troubleshoot if your problem is a community package or an atom package. While running in safe mode see if your problem persists. If it does, it is not a community package.

After I ruled out community packages I basically went through atom's packages trying to narrow down the source of my problem. I would disable 10-20 packages at a time, and then try to reproduce my issue. After doing this 3-4 times, my issue stopped. Eventually I found the buggy package and was able to disable it. My issue immediately stopped.

Atom debugging guide:
https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/

Note:
Make sure atom is up to date with the latest safe build. You could also try completely removing atom from your machine and then reinstalling it.

Note: 
You should also consider that it could be your machine. I recently upgraded from my 2012 MacBook Pro HDD to a Samsung Evo 850 SDD. I was trying to develop a react-native app, and the simulator was painfully slow to where I couldn't do anything. Upgrading the hard drive fixed this problem. (Also since upgrading, atom is much faster.)

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues with lag because *I accidentally initialized a GitHub repo on my desktop* (Mac OS 10.13).

Whenever I opened a project with many files, the lag would increase.  The constant change of file names from grey to green was a clue, I was working on a personal project that was not supposed to be linked to Github so that should not have been happening.

Eventually, I stumbled upon the following link, which helped solve the problem.

[How to remove git repository created on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369850/how-to-remove-git-repository-created-on-desktop)

**Remove the .git file from your desktop**

1. In the main bar navigate to Go -> Home
2. View hidden files using the shortcut SHIFT + COMMAND + PERIOD (.)
3. Find and delete the file ".git"

**A Word of Warning**

*Do not do this if your desktop is your active Github repository.*

For me, I accidentally made my desktop a repository when I started using Github.  It is easy to make the mistake of initializing a git repo from the wrong folder, so this may have happened to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Issues after each typing in the editor:

- high RAM usage
- high CPU usage
- slow response

With the safe mode - it was running fine, so it helped to narrow down the issue to the Community packages.

This was the cause of the issue in my case:

- package called "Pigments":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that Atom was utilizing my machine's gpu which was causing major slowdowns. If your machine has a gpu, consider disabling Atom's usage of it with: `atom --disable-gpu`

For further reading on how to profile Atom, give this [doc a read](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/).